# How to set Apache IoTDB to execute the sql in data files?

Tags: database, time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

Are there any command in Apache IoTDB that can execute the sql in the data files like`-f` in Hive? Or are there any settings I can change in Cli tool of IoTDB to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set Cli tool like this: `start-cli.sh -h <ip> -e "$(cat filename)"` to read and execute the sql statement of the data files in Apache IoTDB.